# How can I develop a game for iOS?

Tags: ios, cocos2d, objective-c

I have a Mac arriving in the next few weeks, and plan to program a 2d game.  I know a little bit of Java but nothing about Objective C.  I've heard about cocos2d -- it seems good but I don't know where to start.  Should I learn Objective C first and use XCode, and postpone learning how to program games?

Comment: Though it doesn't really answer the question, I would like to recommend that you first try to develop an Android app. Android doesn't require you to first buy a Mac. And since you already know Java, all you would have to do, is learn the android SDK.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer but i think with ios apps you can get more downloads. And i only know a little bit.

Comment: I don't see a reason why you would get more downloads, Android has the most market share ATM.

Comment: At this stage in the learning process, really ANYTHING you do will help you move forward and the platform absolutely doesn't matter the least bit. Just be sure to use a stable technology (ie Sprite Kit, libgdx) with lots of documentation and a great community. Google can help you narrow down the popular choices, what tutorials are out there, and check the activity on official forums and stackoverflow/here. Engine feature lists are secondary (or tertiary) to that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If your goal is to make the best use of your time, I would do this:

1. Come up with an idea now.  You can spend all the time in the world programming, but if you don't have a direction, it's all for naught.
2. Start learning Objective C when the computer arrives.
3. Program the game (in Objective C) once you think you can.

Comment: But you need a program like cocos2d to develop it.

Comment: @user42687 Then get a program like cocos2d...  But I thought you could use XCode to program apps?

Comment: @user42687 You don't specially need cocos2d to build a game...

Comment: I think you can program apps with xcode but not games.

Comment: "Come up with an idea now. It's the hardest part of making a game." -1

Comment: Yes i habe an idea

Comment: You clearly misunderstood me. Coming up with the idea is not only (by far) the easiest part; The rest is extremely hard. This is why game companies require teams of focused people to make highly successful games (and sometimes still fail). It is because they require a large amount of challenging work. Small indie do exist but they also require (albeit a smaller portion of) the hard work their larger brethren demand. I wrote (-1) as to state I disapprove in the sense of "thumbs down".

Comment: Saying the hardest part in making a game is coming up with an idea is like saying the hardest part in making a feast is building up the desire to eat.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite Don't know why you decided to come back to a 2-day closed old question just to express your annoyance at my answer, but here we are.  As a 6-year C++ programmer, I agree that making a game is not easy; it takes a lot of time and hard work.  But how many games have you seen that would be great if they spent a little more time developing the gameplay?  And when was the last time you hosted a feast?

Comment: Whilst the question was open I showed my disagreement by commenting. -1 and the OP thought I was supporting the answer by repeating what you said so I took the time to explain it in detail. Yes I agree game-play is important but game-play != idea. If you think about it an idea is like "Windows"(not the OS, the kind of GUI common today). Who thought about it? Xerox possibly ( http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Xerox_8010_compound_document.jpg ) but who is making money out of it? Apple and Microsoft. An idea is zilch. Implementation + marketing is 99.99%.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite Edited the post to more accurately reflect my original intentions.